# How to embed videos in posts or pages in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, video, posts

Hello i have already brought my server videos to medial library by "Add From Server" plugin. Now i'm trying to embed that video to post or pages of wordpress i am unable to embed it, i used many plugins but none of them worked. Any suggetions please.

Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 1):

If your Wordpress install is up-to-date, in your post editor, just click the Add Media button above the post editor, and select your media. Wordpress will build out an HTML5 video tag that will play your video for the majority of site users.